# Iterate through nested ArrayList and crate 2 new ArrayList from values within the nested ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections

**Input:**

```
 mainList= ArrayList size = 4: 0 = {
           expression = ArrayList size = 8: 0 = {
              names: "name"
              values: ArrayList size = 1: {
                 0: "value"
             }
            }
        }
```

I need to iterate over this ArrayList and create 2 new ArrayLists 1 containing a List of Strings from names and 1 containing the list of Strings from values

*Data structure explanation:*

mainList contains an ArrayList of 4 entries, each entry is an ArrayList called expressions which has 8 entries, each entry has a String value 'names' and an ArrayList called 'values' which has a single String value.

I have tried:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> values= new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i < mainList.size(); i++) {
            names.add(mainList.get(i));
              for(int i=0; i < names.size(); i++) {
              values.add(names.get(i));
          }

        }
```

**Desired Output:**

> names = ArrayList size = 8 {name1, name2...name8};
>
> values = ArrayList size = 4 {values1, values2...values4};

Comment: I think you're missing a few levels of nesting in your code.  If I understand your description correctly, you'll need 1) an outer loop to iterate over the expression-lists; 2) a 2nd-level loop to iterate over the expressions in each expression-list; 3) a 3rd-level loop to iterate over the name/values-list pairs in each expression, and 4) a final loop to iterate the individual values in a values-list

Comment: @KevinAnderson Yes that sounds exactly right, I haven't gotten my head fully around the problem and my algorithm is missing a couple iterations